# Function call missing argument list to create pointer

Tags: c++, qt5.2, vrpn

I tried to connect my app to OpenViBE through VRPN server. My app works well until I try to add code to connect my app to VRPN server.

My code looks like this:

`MainWindow.c` code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtUiTools/QUiLoader>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFileDialog>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "vrpn_Analog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    currentImage = 0;
    labelSize = ui->label_2->size();

    createActions();
    openFileDialog();
}
void MainWindow::checkChannels()
{
    vrpn_Analog_Remote *vrpnAnalog = new vrpn_Analog_Remote("Mouse0@localhost");
    vrpnAnalog->register_change_handler( 0, handle_analog );
}


void VRPN_CALLBACK MainWindow::handle_analog( void* userData, const vrpn_ANALOGCB a )
{
 int nbChannels = a.num_channel;

 cout << "Analog : ";

 for( int i=0; i < a.num_channel; i++ )
 {
 cout << a.channel[i] << " ";
 }

 cout << endl;
}
```

`MainWindow.h` code:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileInfoList>

#include "vrpn_Analog.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);

private slots:
    void openFileDialog();    

private:    
    void checkChannels();

    void VRPN_CALLBACK handle_analog( void* userData, const vrpn_ANALOGCB a );

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

With this code, when I try to run my app I get:

```
error: C3867: 'MainWindow::handle_analog': function call missing argument list; use '&MainWindow::handle_analog' to create a pointer to member
```

I try to edit code by error advice, but I get another error:

```
error: C2664: 'vrpn_Analog_Remote::register_change_handler' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void (__stdcall MainWindow::* )(void *,const vrpn_ANALOGCB)' to 'vrpn_ANALOGCHANGEHANDLER'
There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

I search around, but I don't find any usable solution.

Methods `checkChannels` and `handle_analog` I "copy" from this code, where all works fine:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "vrpn_Analog.h"


void VRPN_CALLBACK vrpn_analog_callback(void* user_data, vrpn_ANALOGCB analog)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < analog.num_channel; i++)
    {
        if (analog.channel[i] > 0)
        {

            std::cout << "Analog Channel : " << i << " / Analog Value : " << analog.channel[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    /* flag used to stop the program execution */
    bool running = true;

    /* VRPN Analog object */
    vrpn_Analog_Remote* VRPNAnalog;

    /* Binding of the VRPN Analog to a callback */
    VRPNAnalog = new vrpn_Analog_Remote("openvibe_vrpn_analog@localhost");
    VRPNAnalog->register_change_handler(NULL, vrpn_analog_callback);

    /* The main loop of the program, each VRPN object must be called in order to process data */
    while (running)
    {
        VRPNAnalog->mainloop();
    }

    return 0;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Where I'm doing mistake? Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly call a non-static class method using this callback. This is because the method is expecting to be called with the class `this` pointer.

If you don't need any data from your class, then just make the method static. If you do need data from the class, you can make a static "stub" that takes the class pointer in the userData parameter and then calls the original method. Something like:

Declaration:

```
static void VRPN_CALLBACK handle_analog_stub( void* userData, const vrpn_ANALOGCB a );
```

Definition

```
void VRPN_CALLBACK MainWindow::handle_analog_stub( void* userData, const vrpn_ANALOGCB a )
{
   MainWindow *mainWindow = static_cast<MainWindow*>(userData);
   mainWindow->handle_analog(NULL, a);
}
```

Then when you call the function use:

```
vrpnAnalog->register_change_handler( this, handle_analog_stub );
```

(Updated to static_cast to pointer, thanks rpavlik)

Comment: Specifically, the types of a function pointer and a pointer to a member function are different (because of the `this` pointer, etc.). Also, no need for a C-style cast: you can (should!) do `MainWindow *self = static_cast<MainWindow*>(userData);`, or if you are allowed to use `auto`, `auto self = static_cast<MainWindow*>(userData);` (calling such `this`-equivalent pointers in callbacks `self` is a common idiom I've seen).  You can call a non-static member or just put your code in there using `self->myMember` to access object members.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar error in Visual Studio: `"function call missing argument list; use '&className::functionName' to create a pointer to member"`..

I was just missing the parenthesis when calling the getter, so `className.get_variable_a()`

Comment: I just started back on C++ after a long streak of C#... You saved my bacon x.x

Comment: While this is a related error message, and having this answer here might be helpful to some searchers, I think it's important to note that this is not actually related to or a solution to the problem in the question - see the other answers for that.

Comment: @rpavlik certainly valid for me! I think this is relevant for all us gen-y programmers who grew up on Java, C# and code completion *_*

Answer (score 4):

The error message tells you that the argument you provided does not match `vrpn_ANALOGCHANGEHANDLER`. You didn't show the definition of that. I checked online and it suggested

```
typedef void (*vrpn_ANALOGCHANGEHANDLER)(void *userdata, const vrpn_ANALOGCB info);
```

so I'm going with that.

Your code attempts to pass a pointer-to-member-function, which cannot be converted to a pointer-to-function.  This is because a pointer-to-member-function can only be called on an object, so it wouldn't know what object to use.

If you look at the code you are "copying off", you will see that `vrpn_analog_callback` is a free function. However in your code it is a member function.  You need to change your code so that the callback is a free function (or a static member function).

If your intent is that the callback should call the member function on the same MainWindow object that you are registering the handler on, then do this:

```
// In MainWindow's class definition, add this:
static void VRPN_CALLBACK cb_handle_analog( void* userData, const vrpn_ANALOGCB a )
{
    static_cast<MainWindow *>(userData)->handle_analog(NULL, a);
}

// In checkChannels()
vrpnAnalog->register_change_handler( this, cb_handle_analog );
```