# How to call the function in derived class to process handle_post?(Function call missing argument list to create pointer)

Tags: c++, rest, casablanca

in my base class, this is a public non-static member function:

```
void BaseClass::SetPorcessMethod()
{
     //do something
    Listener.support(methods::POST, this->HandlePost);
    //do something
}
```

In the function above, `Listener` is a static member variable.
Function `HandlePost` is a pure virtual function which is implemented by all derived classes. I want to use `this` pointer to call different `HandlePost` from different derived class. 
Like:

```
class BaseClass
{
 public:
   static http_listener listener;
   void SetPorcessMethod();
   virtual void HandlePost((http_request request) = 0;
   /*listener is init in constructor , not display here*/
}
 class Derived2:public BaseClass
{
  void HandlePost(http_request request);
}
class Derived1:public BaseClass
{
  void HandlePost(http_request request);
}

Derived1 instance1;
instance1.SetPorcessMethod();
Derived2 instance2;
instance2.SetPorcessMethod();
```

However, it displays`BaseClass::HandlePost:function call missing argument list use &BaseClass::HandlePost:function to create a pointer to member`.I know this is because `Your code attempts to pass a pointer-to-member-function, which cannot be converted to a pointer-to-function. This is because a pointer-to-member-function can only be called on an object, so it wouldn't know what object to use.` [Function call missing argument list to create pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207942/function-call-missing-argument-list-to-create-pointer) 
 But what should I do so that I can call the function from derived class with`support()`?

Comment: Something essential is missing from this question because it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @CrazyEddie which information do you need ?

Comment: What part of "use &BaseClass::HandlePost" you didn't understand? Seems like a fairly clear error message, and it is correct: this is the right syntax for specifying a pointer to a class method. Note that this is a pointer to a class method, and not a function, so the second parameter to your `support()` method has better be a `void (BaseClass::*)(http_request)`. If it isn't, you have bigger problems, such as broken class design.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Update the question

Comment: @Eichhörnchen I want to pass the function to support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass a member function to `support`. In order to call such a function the caller need the member function arguments and the pointer to the instance to call the function on.

However `support` expects a `std::function<void(http_request)>`, i.e. without the instance pointer. So you have to wrap the call into another callable which does not need to have the `BaseClass` instance pointer passed. You can do that with a lambda (or `std::bind` if you prefer):

```
Listener.support( methods::POST,
    [this](http_request request){return HandlePost(request);} );

Listener.support( methods::POST,
    std::bind(&BaseClass::HandlePost, this, std::placeholders::_1) );
```

`#include<functional>` for the latter variant.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `support()` expects a `std::function` as input? That is not stated anywhere in the question, edits, or comments. What is stated is that the compiler error is expecting a `pointer-to-function`, so `support()` is actually expecting a plain `void (*)(http_request)` function pointer instead. And you can't use a capturing lambda for that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The question is not clear on it, but considering the tags, I assume that they are using this library: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk. I looked up the signature of `Listener.support` assuming `Listener` is a `http_listener` from that library. Also that quote in the question is not part of the error message, but quoted from another question, I think.

Comment: @firstaccount Does the second one not work? It could be that I made an mistake, if so I'd like to fix it.

Comment: It seems that "&" is illegal when I use the second way.

Comment: @firstaccount Ah yes, I forgot that this syntax is not allowed, one has to be a bit more verbose. I fixed it.